# Adding existing account with different AD Domain

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, user-accounts

I have 2000+ accounts in User Info List with domain e.g, Domain1\User. I want to add all these existing users with different domain e.g, Domain2\User. So that the Users can login with both accounts either with Domain1\User or Domain2\User with same permissions?

All the users are currently in MOSS 2007 Userinfo list. How i do this task?

Answer (score 0):

If all users already moved to different domain then you have to run the migrate user Command for each user. after that user will be able to log in using the Domain2\users. Once migrated then user will no longer available with Domain1\users in sharepoint.

```
stsadm -o migrateuser –oldlogin <domain\name> –newlogin <domain\name> [-ignoresidhistory]
```

But if you want user should login either DOmain1 or Domain 2 then keep in mind couple of things.

1. If you Already Have Domain1\user in SharePoint then You added Domain2\user then SharePoint will treat both as different valid users.
2. SharePoint Will create seprate profile for both.
3. You have to grant the permission on both account seprately.
4. their will be no sync between users.